# Virtuemart Joomla 1.5 product layout bug

Tags: joomla, virtuemart

I'm currently managing a website based on Joomla 1.5 with Virtumart. The site is used to list the products as we are a distribution company. I have a problem with the display of the product pages. Some are fine like:

http://www.anand.co.uk/catalogue/batteries/panalr6b10-apb-panasonic-alkaline-power-aa-4pack.html

But then I have Issues with products such as:

http://www.anand.co.uk/catalogue/smokers-sundries/zig-zag/cigarette-paper/zigredking-zig-zag-red-king-size.html

I've played around with associating the different products with different categories but this hasn't narrowed the problem down. There doesn't appear to be any part of the Virtuemart interface that can control the layout and appears to use tables.

Comment: The CSS from your template.css is conflicting with the VM button. Try creating a template override and assigning a different class.

Comment: What do you think dictates why this happens on only certain products?

Comment: maybe cause on the other page, you have 2 products and therefore the styling may be a little different.